# why do these two functions take such different times to process?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm currently discovering shell and Bash working on a school project.

The function I'm working on needs to count the number of journeys per driver using a CSV file as data.

It therefore checks if the step of the journey is indeed the first (value 1 in column 2) to increment the number of journeys of the driver in an associative array with Awk.

In the process I created two functions and I expected the second one to be much faster, but it's the opposite.

The first I made takes 1 second to process:

```
d1Flag() 
{
    grep ";1;" data/data.csv > temp/temp.csv
    awk -F ';' '{ count[$6]++ }
      END { for (i in count) print i" " count[i] }' temp/temp.csv > temp/temp2.csv
    sort -k3,3 -rn temp/temp2.csv | head -n10
}
```

The second I made takes 6 seconds to process:

```
d1Flag() 
{
    awk -v OFS=';' -F';|\r' '$2==1 { journey_count[$6]++ }
      END {for (driver in journey_count) print driver, journey_count[driver] } ' data/data.csv |
    sort -t';' -nrk2,2 | head -n10 > temp/temp.csv
}
```

I'm wondering why it takes so much time for the second. Is it just Awk that's overly slow? Is there a problem in the second implementation?

Comment: What does `data/data.csv` look like? How big is it? How long is each record? These things will matter.

Comment: In some cases you'd be better off restructuring the awk logic to skip lines that don't match early instead of using grep at all. grep _is_ faster than awk in terms of throughout, but not by such a huge amount; it's more important to pay attention to getting your algorithms right and (say) doing constant-time things before you do O(n^2) things.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you can publish data that reproduces the stated timings, that would make it possible for people who aren't you to concretely test and compare answers; otherwise we don't know what the constant factors are (f/e, what percentage of inputs the grep discards, the actual size of journey_count, etc).

Comment: Tangentially, you want to avoid temporary files where you can. The first can be refactored to `grep ";1;" data/data.csv | awk -F ';' '{ count[$6]++ } END { for (i in count) print i" " count[i] }' | sort -k3,3 -rn | head -n10` where additionally you could get rid of the [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: If you _don't_ get rid of the temporary files, ideally use something like `mktemp` to avoid various security and stability issues.

Comment: Same without awk `grep '^[^;]*;1;' some.csv | cut -d';' -f 6 | sort | uniq --count | sort -nr -k1,1`. Just print driver name and let `uniq -c` do the count.

Comment: Why does the 2nd awk require `-F';|\r'` (a slow regular expression) when the first just uses `-F';'` (a fast literal character)? If you pipe the output from both awks to the same `sort` command (no `| head`), do they both produce the same output and, if not, what;s the difference?

Comment: Looking at your first solution, could it be that data.csv is really much larger than temp.csv?

Answer (score 5):

Isolate and test the differences in your logic. Every detail can be relevant.

To compare the specific differences, I made a test file consisting of two longish records repeated over and over.

```
$: ls -l data.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 561001980 Dec 21 08:28 data.csv

$: head -2 data.csv
foo;1;bar;baz;qux;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
foo;nope;bar;baz;qux;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
```

First, I checked the functions with minimal changes, mostly just moving the files to the local directory. Note that *could* matter, but for this test I didn't want to pollute it with the possibility of different types of mount points, as that is a less likely issue.

For the record, on my laptop I see very little differences in these as written:

```
$: . v1; time d1Flag >x; . v2; time d1Flag

real    0m1.064s
user    0m0.670s
sys     0m0.434s

real    0m1.052s
user    0m0.905s
sys     0m0.262s
```

Then I copied your two `awk` commands into a file to `time` them *against the same file*, to isolate their logic away from the possibility that the `grep` is the big time saver.
(I formatted and edited the variables to look the same just to more clearly make evident what little *was* different.)
I ran it with surprising results:

```
$: cat t2; . t2; . t2; . t2
 time awk            -F ';'    '      { count[$6]++ } END { for (i in count) print i" " count[i] }' data.csv > x
 time awk -v OFS=';' -F ';|\r' '$2==1 { count[$6]++ } END { for (i in count) print i,   count[i] }' data.csv > x

real    0m0.662s
user    0m0.499s
sys     0m0.186s

real    0m1.165s
user    0m0.953s
sys     0m0.187s

real    0m0.634s
user    0m0.452s
sys     0m0.171s

real    0m1.118s
user    0m0.937s
sys     0m0.171s

real    0m0.629s
user    0m0.421s
sys     0m0.202s

real    0m1.121s
user    0m0.906s
sys     0m0.218s
```

The first is significantly faster.

To further isolate the difference, I took the carriage return out of the `-F`ield delimiters, but changed nothing else, and ran it again.

```
$: cat t2; . t2; . t2; . t2
 time awk            -F ';' '      { count[$6]++ } END { for (i in count) print i" " count[i] }' data.csv > x
 time awk -v OFS=';' -F ';' '$2==1 { count[$6]++ } END { for (i in count) print i,   count[i] }' data.csv > x

real    0m0.574s
user    0m0.405s
sys     0m0.186s

real    0m0.561s
user    0m0.421s
sys     0m0.124s

real    0m0.560s
user    0m0.390s
sys     0m0.202s

real    0m0.574s
user    0m0.468s
sys     0m0.109s

real    0m0.575s
user    0m0.343s
sys     0m0.218s

real    0m0.556s
user    0m0.437s
sys     0m0.124s
```

That was apparently it. Now their times are quite comparable, and in fact the second was just a bit *faster* most of the time.

Comment: I meant to separately ask what the `\r` was doing there anyway. Perhaps the OP can explain what they were hoping it would do, and/or provide test data where adding it actually makes a (useful) difference?

Comment: My assumption was that they were using that as a way to chomp them off the end of records. I suspect an *anchored* `sub(/\r$/,"")` would be faster, and probably should have tested that before I deleted my working space, but it wasn't done at all in the first version, so I just isolated it as the relevant difference. Maybe I'll play with it again in a bit. :)

Comment: Right, splitting on regular expressions is slower than splitting on literal characters, and the bigger an array gets the slower lookups of it's indices are (**much** slower if the initial array memory allocation is exceeded) so only populating it for the `$2==1` lines would speed it up.

Comment: And he grep already did an efficient fixed-character cull of nonmatching records in v1, so the time was pretty good there. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine your input file looks like this:

```
$ cat file
x;1;foo;bar
x;0;foo;bar
x;0;foo;bar
x;0;foo;bar
x;1;foo;bar
x;0;foo;bar
```

i.e. it is 6 lines long, with 4 `;`-separated fields per line, 2 of those 6 lines have `1` as the second field. Here are the things that are slowing down the awk command in your second script given that input:

**1) Field Splitting:** When you reference any field in your script, e.g. `$2`, awk has to split every input line (record) into fields. With your first script you are effectively doing:

```
grep ';1;' file | awk -F';' '{...}'
```

grep does not do field splitting and awk has to perform field splitting on just the 2 lines that have `1` as their second field whereas with your second script:

```
awk -F';|\r' '$2 == 1{...}' file
```

awk has to perform field splitting on all 6 of the lines in the input before discarding 4 of them. So that's 2 rounds of field splitting vs 6.

**2) Regexp vs String Field Separator:** Splitting a string into fields using a character is much faster than splitting a string into fields by searching for and matching on a regular expression. Your first awk command:

```
awk -F';' '{...}'
```

is splitting the line into fields using the single character `;` while the second one:

```
awk -F';|\r' '$2 == 1{...}' file
```

is splitting the line into fields by matching on the regular expression `;|\r` which is slower.

Given a 10 million line input file where 10% of the lines have a `1` in the 2nd field as produced by this command:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=10000000; i++) printf "x;%d;foo;bar\n", i%10}' > file10m
```

Look at the relative timing of the combinations of the above cases:

a) field splitting on **10%** of the input using a **character** FS:

```
$ time grep ';1;' file10m | awk -F';' '{print $2}' > /dev/null

real    0m0.286s
user    0m0.233s
sys     0m0.015s
```

b) field splitting on **10%** of the input using a **regexp** FS:

```
$ time grep ';1;' file10m | awk -F';|\r' '{print $2}' > /dev/null

real    0m0.908s
user    0m0.953s
sys     0m0.046s
```

c) field splitting on **all** of the input using a **character** FS:

```
$ time awk -F';' '$2==1{print $2}' file10m > /dev/null

real    0m1.356s
user    0m1.281s
sys     0m0.015s
```

d) field splitting on **all** of the input using a **regexp** FS:

```
$ time awk -F';|\r' '$2==1{print $2}' file10m > /dev/null

real    0m7.952s
user    0m7.734s
sys     0m0.015s
```

and what you're asking about is the difference between your 2 scripts written as "a" and "d" above.

Lastly, this probably isn't really an issue for your example but since we can't see the input and so don't know if `awk -F';' '$2 == "1"'` is equivalent to `grep ";"` or not, MAYBE your array is bigger for the second one. If that is the case then...

**3) Memory Allocation:** Awk allocates memory for arrays dynamically. The first time you use an array awk will allocate some number of bytes, lets say 100 bytes (obviously in reality it's much bigger than that). As you fill the array and reach the existing memory limit awk has to allocate more memory for the array and so it has to decide how much more to allocate. In GNU awk (and, I expect others), the next block size that gets allocated isn't another 100 or even 100*2, it's 100^2, i.e. 10000 bytes and if that new limit is approached later then 10000^2, i.e. 100000000, bytes get allocated. The larger the array gets the slower array lookup operations become.

Answer (score 1):

While the second implementation fits in less lines, it is running `awk` on a larger file than in the first implementation.

In other words, since you're extracting *valid rows in your first implementation, `awk` has less lines to process.

---

**The grep'd rows are all of which have a 1 as a column value (anywhere), not necessarily just the ones in the second column.*

See:

```
d1Flag() {
    grep '^[^;]*;1;' data/data.csv > temp/temp.csv
    awk -F ';' '{ if ($2 == 1) { count[$6]++ } } END { for (i in count) print i" " count[i] }' temp/temp.csv > temp/temp2.csv
    sort -k3,3 -rn temp/temp2.csv | head -n10
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but couldn't prove out out with testing. The field parsing on the second adds a carriage return, though, and removing that made the times for the `awk` *on the same file* faster.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and as some of you said grep is a big time saver here.

Using grep to isolate the lines with a 1 on the second column makes process time go from 5s to 1s.

in addition to that using no useless temp files in the process makes it go to 0.5s .

Heres the final command line

```
d1Flag()
{
    grep '^[^;]*;1;' data/data.csv | awk -v OFS=';' -F';' '{ journey_count[$6]++ } END {for (driver in journey_count) print driver, journey_count[driver] } ' | sort -t';' -nrk2,2 | head -n10 > temp/temp_d1.csv  
}
```